# PDF file become corrupted if the document is too long - itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, corrupt

I print PDF files with itextsharp, and when I try to print longer files with like 440 pages, the browsers (Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome) and Adobe Reader says that it's corrupted, and leave some pages blank at the begginning.
Example (with a file with 440 pages):
Google Chrome: leave 385 pages blank, and shows 55 pages as it should be.
Mozilla Firefox: leave 163 pages blank, and shows 277 pages as it should be.
Adobe Acrobat Reader (on computer): shows about 100 pages correctly.
The Adobe Reader on Android can show it perfectly.
Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance for your answers.

---

**Update**

Thank you for your answers! I currently use 5.5.3.0 version, I'll try it out with newer versions.

Comment: Cool. You seem to already have a solution.

Comment: This is a known problem with iText 5.2 and the reason why all iText 5.2 versions were removed from all known repositories. Note that the number of pages is irrelevant if you are using iText 5.2. If you are not using iText 5.2, then you need to provide more info because I've created PDFs with thousands of pages that open correctly.

Comment: Also note that the name **iTextSharp** was abandoned 2 years ago in favor of the name **iText for .NET**. The current version is 7.1.2. If you are using a version older than 5.3, please be aware that there used to be a limit on the file size due to the internal use of integer values instead of long values for the byte positions.

Comment: Please update your question by providing extra information otherwise you risk that your question will be closed because no one can reproduce the problem.